# Certificate Format with 64 line break

Tags: javascript

How to format a certificate with new lines.

Attached is the sample code and also a sampleCert.txt(un-formatted) and expected format - formatCert.txt.

Testing via java script.

```
function parsecert(splitArr) {
    var parseArr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < splitArr.length; i++) {
        if (i === 0 || i === 1 || i === splitArr.length - 2 || i === splitArr.length - 1)
            continue;
        else parseArr.push(splitArr[i]);
    }
    var beginStr = '-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----';
    var endStr = '-----END CERTIFICATE-----';
    parseArr.unshift(beginStr);
    parseArr.push(endStr);
    parseArr.join("\r\n");
    console.log(parseArr);
    return parseArr;
}
```

Unable to get the expected result..
sampleCert.txt(input):

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- MIIIPDCCBySgAwIBAgIQB2XGTnTlkdaAOcoqhHVj8DANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADBw MQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzEVMBMGA1UEChMMRGlnaUNlcnQgSW5jMRkwFwYDVQQLExB3 d3cuZGlnaWNlcnQuY29tMS8wLQYDVQQDEyZEaWdpQ2VydCBTSEEyIEhpZ2ggQXNz dXJhbmNlIFNlcnZlciBDQTAeFw0xODEwMDUwMDAwMDBaFw0xOTA4MTQxMjAwMDBa MGoxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVTMQswCQYDVQQIEwJOWTERMA8GA1UEBxMITmV3IFlvcmsx HTAbBgNVBAoTFFN0YWNrIEV4Y2hhbmdlLCBJbmMuMRwwGgYDVQQDDBMqLnN0YWNr ZXhjaGFuZ2UuY29tMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA9Kk6 NXUP1ocXt89mT1cIxadBhzCL0YTqP01/DSotUHRzV70qOCT7AdMT0K1Ji6rFyapz RiqUIhAkhEseXRp0MNr21fSUw4VoCb+ImO6gnIlzolkhrpK6Iy34KyU3zyt8XYD+ mY3i8GjPZOysRJNLy3ouQBmzuOmU/2FomnmiEGF02mVgb3ev8Prcnt7dCiF7liBI sd3zkPeXvTVYcVcb/MBrFEzc4FuIuphTiJboNz8wHv9+PXAXUUH8TESrUfFPCKJH wd9EAoNX8jPU1TIxiCoe6XN5E1mPyGgyvEnacH/HerK/eLc46L7YWVGRyjHWaaTK 0rJhKgkh59qsWBdn5wIDAQABo4IE1jCCBNIwHwYDVR0jBBgwFoAUUWj/kK8CB3U8 zNllZGKiErhZcjswHQYDVR0OBBYEFJqKwW7B8k362XsC1I+zA6xqPcZYMIIB/AYD VR0RBIIB8zCCAe+CEyouc3RhY2tleGNoYW5nZS5jb22CEXN0YWNrZXhjaGFuZ2Uu Y29tghFzdGFja292ZXJmbG93LmNvbYITKi5zdGFja292ZXJmbG93LmNvbYINc3Rh Y2thdXRoLmNvbYILc3N0YXRpYy5uZXSCDSouc3N0YXRpYy5uZXSCD3NlcnZlcmZh dWx0LmNvbYIRKi5zZXJ2ZXJmYXVsdC5jb22CDXN1cGVydXNlci5jb22CDyouc3Vw ZXJ1c2VyLmNvbYINc3RhY2thcHBzLmNvbYIUb3BlbmlkLnN0YWNrYXV0aC5jb22C GCoubWV0YS5zdGFja2V4Y2hhbmdlLmNvbYIWbWV0YS5zdGFja2V4Y2hhbmdlLmNv bYIQbWF0aG92ZXJmbG93Lm5ldIISKi5tYXRob3ZlcmZsb3cubmV0gg1hc2t1YnVu dHUuY29tgg8qLmFza3VidW50dS5jb22CEXN0YWNrc25pcHBldHMubmV0ghIqLmJs b2dvdmVyZmxvdy5jb22CEGJsb2dvdmVyZmxvdy5jb22CGCoubWV0YS5zdGFja292 ZXJmbG93LmNvbYIVKi5zdGFja292ZXJmbG93LmVtYWlsghNzdGFja292ZXJmbG93 LmVtYWlsghJzdGFja292ZXJmbG93LmJsb2cwDgYDVR0PAQH/BAQDAgWgMB0GA1Ud JQQWMBQGCCsGAQUFBwMBBggrBgEFBQcDAjB1BgNVHR8EbjBsMDSgMqAwhi5odHRw Oi8vY3JsMy5kaWdpY2VydC5jb20vc2hhMi1oYS1zZXJ2ZXItZzYuY3JsMDSgMqAw hi5odHRwOi8vY3JsNC5kaWdpY2VydC5jb20vc2hhMi1oYS1zZXJ2ZXItZzYuY3Js MEwGA1UdIARFMEMwNwYJYIZIAYb9bAEBMCowKAYIKwYBBQUHAgEWHGh0dHBzOi8v d3d3LmRpZ2ljZXJ0LmNvbS9DUFMwCAYGZ4EMAQICMIGDBggrBgEFBQcBAQR3MHUw JAYIKwYBBQUHMAGGGGh0dHA6Ly9vY3NwLmRpZ2ljZXJ0LmNvbTBNBggrBgEFBQcw AoZBaHR0cDovL2NhY2VydHMuZGlnaWNlcnQuY29tL0RpZ2lDZXJ0U0hBMkhpZ2hB c3N1cmFuY2VTZXJ2ZXJDQS5jcnQwDAYDVR0TAQH/BAIwADCCAQYGCisGAQQB1nkC BAIEgfcEgfQA8gB3AKS5CZC0GFgUh7sTosxncAo8NZgE+RvfuON3zQ7IDdwQAAAB ZkIJ+SMAAAQDAEgwRgIhAPCadxv47cB4QOOvN9s/R23EepEbSI4/MuAdf5vKeU79 AiEA2gZ3O8nzuUVanRW9fg6mgfsL08Nn/ZGm73O/F3IGX2UAdwCHdb/nWXz4jEOZ X73zbv9WjUdWNv9KtWDBtOr/XqCDDwAAAWZCCfoGAAAEAwBIMEYCIQDQjfmVBq+/ y2gBK/eE9x6jz9hTZ5tIfhkStS85fMAxegIhAMAuNkyuO4t06EiEgMWialJZuAnk Qw29GceIBG8r1Ap3MA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAA4IBAQAAk873/+2QswKfJSQn+iZe Zc8uiGg99pmd008E2cmGErqNzPclK9INbPjwxl9zIgTcXpF/UtBVVS1Z7Xo83qfs GMPdMzYt3F+hQpQYLhlGF+5Jf2x6Zb1zjT/aM3GMdGi+6OPV+YHl/wgUe45N6kRu DZnVL167+W3l2nD+mShO/7xqwHiZuz0GHyBHRp5i43blH0vg67sJ8guN81papupY 2v78FcvR8j0ELfgyehtWpjF3vzKSq/rY2sMXTYzSPqMeksseHNhSMYU6Ww9h9pyM aVnw9vahqf7nKHHcC2VRTUgkQfn9yDmmBOo0nQ8Xgfpd65/PaxVfBnuKfEkXBfpM -----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

formatCert.txt(expected output)

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n
MIIIPDCCBySgAwIBAgIQB2XGTnTlkdaAOcoqhHVj8DANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADBw\n
MQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzEVMBMGA1UEChMMRGlnaUNlcnQgSW5jMRkwFwYDVQQLExB3\n
d3cuZGlnaWNlcnQuY29tMS8wLQYDVQQDEyZEaWdpQ2VydCBTSEEyIEhpZ2ggQXNz\n
dXJhbmNlIFNlcnZlciBDQTAeFw0xODEwMDUwMDAwMDBaFw0xOTA4MTQxMjAwMDBa\n
MGoxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVTMQswCQYDVQQIEwJOWTERMA8GA1UEBxMITmV3IFlvcmsx\n
HTAbBgNVBAoTFFN0YWNrIEV4Y2hhbmdlLCBJbmMuMRwwGgYDVQQDDBMqLnN0YWNr\n
ZXhjaGFuZ2UuY29tMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA9Kk6\n
NXUP1ocXt89mT1cIxadBhzCL0YTqP01/DSotUHRzV70qOCT7AdMT0K1Ji6rFyapz\n
RiqUIhAkhEseXRp0MNr21fSUw4VoCb+ImO6gnIlzolkhrpK6Iy34KyU3zyt8XYD+\n
mY3i8GjPZOysRJNLy3ouQBmzuOmU/2FomnmiEGF02mVgb3ev8Prcnt7dCiF7liBI\n
sd3zkPeXvTVYcVcb/MBrFEzc4FuIuphTiJboNz8wHv9+PXAXUUH8TESrUfFPCKJH\n
wd9EAoNX8jPU1TIxiCoe6XN5E1mPyGgyvEnacH/HerK/eLc46L7YWVGRyjHWaaTK\n
0rJhKgkh59qsWBdn5wIDAQABo4IE1jCCBNIwHwYDVR0jBBgwFoAUUWj/kK8CB3U8\n
zNllZGKiErhZcjswHQYDVR0OBBYEFJqKwW7B8k362XsC1I+zA6xqPcZYMIIB/AYD\n
VR0RBIIB8zCCAe+CEyouc3RhY2tleGNoYW5nZS5jb22CEXN0YWNrZXhjaGFuZ2Uu\n
Y29tghFzdGFja292ZXJmbG93LmNvbYITKi5zdGFja292ZXJmbG93LmNvbYINc3Rh\n
Y2thdXRoLmNvbYILc3N0YXRpYy5uZXSCDSouc3N0YXRpYy5uZXSCD3NlcnZlcmZh\n
dWx0LmNvbYIRKi5zZXJ2ZXJmYXVsdC5jb22CDXN1cGVydXNlci5jb22CDyouc3Vw\n
ZXJ1c2VyLmNvbYINc3RhY2thcHBzLmNvbYIUb3BlbmlkLnN0YWNrYXV0aC5jb22C\n
GCoubWV0YS5zdGFja2V4Y2hhbmdlLmNvbYIWbWV0YS5zdGFja2V4Y2hhbmdlLmNv\n
bYIQbWF0aG92ZXJmbG93Lm5ldIISKi5tYXRob3ZlcmZsb3cubmV0gg1hc2t1YnVu\n
dHUuY29tgg8qLmFza3VidW50dS5jb22CEXN0YWNrc25pcHBldHMubmV0ghIqLmJs\n
b2dvdmVyZmxvdy5jb22CEGJsb2dvdmVyZmxvdy5jb22CGCoubWV0YS5zdGFja292\n
ZXJmbG93LmNvbYIVKi5zdGFja292ZXJmbG93LmVtYWlsghNzdGFja292ZXJmbG93\n
LmVtYWlsghJzdGFja292ZXJmbG93LmJsb2cwDgYDVR0PAQH/BAQDAgWgMB0GA1Ud\n
JQQWMBQGCCsGAQUFBwMBBggrBgEFBQcDAjB1BgNVHR8EbjBsMDSgMqAwhi5odHRw\n
Oi8vY3JsMy5kaWdpY2VydC5jb20vc2hhMi1oYS1zZXJ2ZXItZzYuY3JsMDSgMqAw\n
hi5odHRwOi8vY3JsNC5kaWdpY2VydC5jb20vc2hhMi1oYS1zZXJ2ZXItZzYuY3Js\n
MEwGA1UdIARFMEMwNwYJYIZIAYb9bAEBMCowKAYIKwYBBQUHAgEWHGh0dHBzOi8v\n
d3d3LmRpZ2ljZXJ0LmNvbS9DUFMwCAYGZ4EMAQICMIGDBggrBgEFBQcBAQR3MHUw\n
JAYIKwYBBQUHMAGGGGh0dHA6Ly9vY3NwLmRpZ2ljZXJ0LmNvbTBNBggrBgEFBQcw\n
AoZBaHR0cDovL2NhY2VydHMuZGlnaWNlcnQuY29tL0RpZ2lDZXJ0U0hBMkhpZ2hB\n
c3N1cmFuY2VTZXJ2ZXJDQS5jcnQwDAYDVR0TAQH/BAIwADCCAQYGCisGAQQB1nkC\n
BAIEgfcEgfQA8gB3AKS5CZC0GFgUh7sTosxncAo8NZgE+RvfuON3zQ7IDdwQAAAB\n
ZkIJ+SMAAAQDAEgwRgIhAPCadxv47cB4QOOvN9s/R23EepEbSI4/MuAdf5vKeU79\n
AiEA2gZ3O8nzuUVanRW9fg6mgfsL08Nn/ZGm73O/F3IGX2UAdwCHdb/nWXz4jEOZ\n
X73zbv9WjUdWNv9KtWDBtOr/XqCDDwAAAWZCCfoGAAAEAwBIMEYCIQDQjfmVBq+/\n
y2gBK/eE9x6jz9hTZ5tIfhkStS85fMAxegIhAMAuNkyuO4t06EiEgMWialJZuAnk\n
Qw29GceIBG8r1Ap3MA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAA4IBAQAAk873/+2QswKfJSQn+iZe\n
Zc8uiGg99pmd008E2cmGErqNzPclK9INbPjwxl9zIgTcXpF/UtBVVS1Z7Xo83qfs\n
GMPdMzYt3F+hQpQYLhlGF+5Jf2x6Zb1zjT/aM3GMdGi+6OPV+YHl/wgUe45N6kRu\n
DZnVL167+W3l2nD+mShO/7xqwHiZuz0GHyBHRp5i43blH0vg67sJ8guN81papupY\n
2v78FcvR8j0ELfgyehtWpjF3vzKSq/rY2sMXTYzSPqMeksseHNhSMYU6Ww9h9pyM\n
aVnw9vahqf7nKHHcC2VRTUgkQfn9yDmmBOo0nQ8Xgfpd65/PaxVfBnuKfEkXBfpM\n
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Comment: What is the value of `splitArr`? `parseArr.join("\r\n")` returns a new string value. I guess you want to return that value instead of `parseArr` itself.

Comment: splitArr is the input cert(sampleCert) string. Just need to pass unformatted cert string to formatcert with new line characters.

Comment: `"-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----" + inputString.replace(/-+[^-]+-+|\s/g, "").replace(/(?=([^-]{64})*$)/g, "\n") + "-----END CERTIFICATE-----"`

Comment: If `splitArr` is actually a string (as you say) then `for (var i = 0; i < splitArr.length; i++) {` will iterate over every character of the array and you are inserting a line break after every character.

Answer (score 0):

`parseArr.join("\r\n");` will return a new string but it will not make any change to `parseArr` array. So it will be same as it was before `parseArr.join("\r\n");` line.

You should use `return parseArr.join("\r\n");` then it will return the string which will be having newline.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using `replace` with the `g` flag ?

```
var newStr = myStr.replace(/ /g, "\n");
```

`myStr = 'MIIIPDCCBySgAwIBA...'` . then you can append `beginStr` and `endStr` easily.

Here you can run the code:
https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-babbage-vpg7n